# Calculating Cost of Sales in SQL using FIFO method

Tags: sql, sql-server, fifo

From a stock transaction table I've created following sorted view table to be ready for FIFO:

| rowN | date_ | stockCode | sign_ | amount | unitPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '2022-01-20' | ABC | in | 5 | 29.20 |
| 2 | '2022-01-22' | ABC | in | 3 | 32.50 |
| 3 | '2022-01-23' | ABC | out | 7 | 40.00 |
| 4 | '2022-01-23' | ABC | out | 1 | 42.00 |
| 5 | '2022-01-01' | XYZ | in | 3 | 20.50 |
| 6 | '2022-01-03' | XYZ | out | 3 | 25.00 |

and I want to create a select query which looks like the previous table with only "out" rows and added cost_of_sales columns which is FIFO cost of that sale. But my knowledge of SQL is limited by just joins and sum over partitions.

The resulting table in my mind should look like this:

| rowN | date_ | stockCode | sign_ | amount | unitPrice | cost_of_sales_uP | cost_of_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | '2022-01-23' | ABC | out | 7 | 40.00 | 30.1428 | 211.00 |
| 4 | '2022-01-23' | ABC | out | 1 | 42.00 | 32.50 | 32.50 |
| 6 | '2022-01-03' | XYZ | out | 3 | 25.00 | 20.50 | 61.50 |

I have no idea how to achieve this. Any help and guidance is appreciated. Result table doesn't have to be exactly like that but the main idea is there.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Also please show and explain how to do you get the value for `cost_of_sales_uP` and `cost_of_sales`

Comment: I've been all over the place and didn't even come close to be honest. So, I can't show anything worthwile without making it confusing.
I've filled the cost_of_sales columns manually using FIFO method. (First in First Out) For example of the sale on rowN 3:  In order to sell 7 of stock ABC; I get 5 of 29.20 cost and 2 of 32.50 cost. which averages for unit price 30.1428 and a total of 211.00. so last table isn't a result of a code rather than "should be" table.

Comment: I did find this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65074619/how-to-value-cost-of-sales-using-fifo-in-sql-server?rq=1) but I don't have the SalesQty in the initial table like them. my table is mixed with sales and purchases.

Comment: you can use cte. Example `with StockIn as (select * from tbl where sign_ = 'in'), StockOut as (select * from tbl where sign_ = 'out') . . .`

Comment: Apparently the [FIFO stock inventory problem](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/performance-sql-server/t-sql-window-function-speed-phreakery-the-fifo-stock-inventory-problem/) is a common one. But it's one of the hardest problems to solve in SQL alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following method might not be the fastest.
But it gets the job done.

First the incoming are unfolded into a temp table.

Then, by looping over the outgoing, each incoming unit is assigned to an outgoing on a First-In-First-Out basis.

The final query then uses the results of the temp table to calculate the total & average of the incoming.

> ```
> IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpStock') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpStock;
> CREATE TABLE #tmpStock (
>   id int identity primary key,
>   code varchar(30),
>   date_in date,
>   rowN int,
>   unitPrice decimal(10,2),
>   rowN_out int
> );
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- Using a recursive CTE to unfold the incoming for the temp table
> --
> with RCTE as (
>  select stockCode, date_, rowN, amount, unitPrice
>  , 1 as lvl
>  from stock_transactions
>  where sign_ = 'in'
>  
>  union all
>  
>  select stockCode, date_, rowN, amount, unitPrice
>  , lvl + 1
>  from RCTE
>  where lvl < amount
> )
> insert into #tmpStock (code, date_in, rowN, unitPrice)
> select stockCode, date_, rowN, unitPrice
> from RCTE
> order by stockCode, date_, rowN
> option (maxrecursion 0);
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @IdOut INT = 1;
> DECLARE @RowsOut INT = 0;
> DECLARE @code VARCHAR(30);
> DECLARE @amount SMALLINT;
> DECLARE @date DATE;
> DECLARE @rowN INT;
>
> DECLARE @StockOut TABLE (
>   id int identity primary key, 
>   code varchar(30),
>   date_out date, 
>   rowN int,
>   amount smallint
> );
>
> insert into @StockOut (code, date_out, rowN, amount)
> select stockCode, date_, rowN, amount
> from stock_transactions
> where sign_ = 'out'
> order by stockCode, date_, rowN;
>
> SELECT @RowsOut = COUNT(*) FROM @StockOut;
>  
> WHILE @IdOut <= @RowsOut
> BEGIN
>    SELECT 
>      @code = code
>    , @amount = amount
>    , @date = date_out
>    , @rowN = rowN
>    FROM @StockOut
>    WHERE id = @IdOut;
>
>    ;WITH cte_in as (
>      select *
>      , rn = row_number() over (order by date_in, rowN)
>      from #tmpStock 
>      where code = @code 
>        and date_in <= @date
>        and rowN_out is null
>    ) 
>    UPDATE cte_in 
>    SET rowN_out = @rowN
>    WHERE rn <= @amount;
>
>    SET @IdOut = @IdOut + 1;
> END;
> ```

> ```
> select * from #tmpStock
> ```
>
> ```
> id | code | date_in    | rowN | unitPrice | rowN_out
> -: | :--- | :--------- | ---: | --------: | -------:
>  1 | ABC  | 2022-01-20 |    1 |     29.20 |        3
>  2 | ABC  | 2022-01-20 |    1 |     29.20 |        3
>  3 | ABC  | 2022-01-20 |    1 |     29.20 |        3
>  4 | ABC  | 2022-01-20 |    1 |     29.20 |        3
>  5 | ABC  | 2022-01-20 |    1 |     29.20 |        3
>  6 | ABC  | 2022-01-22 |    2 |     32.50 |        3
>  7 | ABC  | 2022-01-22 |    2 |     32.50 |        3
>  8 | ABC  | 2022-01-22 |    2 |     32.50 |        4
>  9 | XYZ  | 2022-01-01 |    5 |     20.50 |        6
> 10 | XYZ  | 2022-01-01 |    5 |     20.50 |        6
> 11 | XYZ  | 2022-01-01 |    5 |     20.50 |        6
> ```

> ```
> SELECT o.*
> , CAST(i.AveragePriceIn AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS cost_of_sales_uP
> , i.TotalPriceIn AS cost_of_sales
> FROM stock_transactions o
> LEFT JOIN (
>   SELECT rowN_out
>   , AVG(unitPrice) as AveragePriceIn
>   , SUM(unitPrice) as TotalPriceIn
>   FROM #tmpStock
>   GROUP BY rowN_out
> ) i on i.rowN_out = o.rowN
> WHERE o.sign_ = 'out'
> ORDER BY o.rowN;
> ```
>
> ```
> rowN | date_      | stockCode | sign_ | amount | unitPrice | cost_of_sales_uP | cost_of_sales
> ---: | :--------- | :-------- | :---- | -----: | --------: | ---------------: | ------------:
>    3 | 2022-01-23 | ABC       | out   |      7 |     40.00 |            30.14 |        211.00
>    4 | 2022-01-23 | ABC       | out   |      1 |     42.00 |            32.50 |         32.50
>    6 | 2022-01-03 | XYZ       | out   |      3 |     25.00 |            20.50 |         61.50
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=04ac2580f562d38b7985f684017584fa)*

Comment: thank you so so much for this. Sorry for the delayed confirmation due to a personal matter. This worked beautifully. I only had to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` after the cte.